# Touch detection problems with custom View inside UIView NOT UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiview, uitextfield, gesture-recognition

I was googling for a while and I found similar problems but when the custom View is inside a ScrollView, but that is not my case.

I have a custom view that consists of a UILabel behind a UITextField, so I can animate that label later.

The problem is that when I add a View in my ViewController and in the Identity Inspector I set the Class as my custom class, when I use the application the UITextField within my custom view does not receive the touches well and it takes time to gain focus and therefore to open the keyboard. The strange thing is that if I move that same arrangement of views to my main ViewController in Storyboard everything works fine. Why doesn't it do it when I place it using the described method?

I plans to reuse this custom view a lot, so putting logic and views in each ViewController is not an option.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest coming up with as simple an example of this problem as you can, then present it here with code, screenshots of InterfaceBuilder & running app, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was in the constraints of the container UIView. That means, the UIView in my main ViewController. The Height of the UIView was a little bit smaller than the space required for my custom view, so although my custom view seemed to draw correctly, it was not receiving the gestures correctly. The solution was simply increase the height to the correct value occupied by my custom View. Thanks a lot!